# Design pattern for DataEngineer-ETL-pandas

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, data-science, etl, procedural-programming

I used to be a Web Backend Developper (using Symfony and Spring-boot).
Now, I'm interested in Data Engineering with Python ... and I see that we use Procedural way more that OOP paradigm.

That is not a big deal but for example, when we do ETL with pandas and all his functionnality, isn't there a structure of programming like MVC but especially for ETL ?
I think that it would be better if everyone followed the same pattern of programming especially that a pipeline could easily turn to be a spaghetti code.